# Chain Rule (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

Proposition:
Let $\phi$ be a function that is (real) differentiable in $A$ and let $\gamma: [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow A$ be differentiable in [a,b], then:
$(\phi \circ \gamma)'(t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \phi(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)+\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} \phi(\gamma(t))\overline{\gamma}'(t)$

In the book I am reading this Proposition is just there without a proof. I can't really figure out how to get to this result.

And the second thing is, as I tried to proof the above the result I got was:
$(\phi \circ \gamma)'(t)=$$\phi '(\gamma (t))\gamma '(t)$

Which one of them is the correct one (or are both correct)?

Comment: Since you are not assuming that $\phi$ is complex-differentiable, what does $\phi'$ mean?

Comment: $\phi'(t):=Re(\phi)'(t)+i Im(\phi)'(t)$ , is the definiton that I use

Comment: For functions whose domain is an interval of $\Bbb R$, I suppose. That's not the case here, as far as $\phi$ is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the usual real chain rule

$$(\phi \circ \gamma)^\prime(t)=\phi^\prime (\gamma (t))\gamma^\prime (t)$$
when you use the Cauchy Riemann relations

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z}&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
\end{cases}$$

In details, you have

$$\gamma^\prime(t) = \gamma_x^\prime(t) + i \gamma_y^\prime(t)$$ hence
$$\begin{cases}
\gamma_x^\prime(t) &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^\prime(t)+\overline\gamma^\prime(t)\right)\\
\gamma_y^\prime(t) &= \frac{1}{2i}\left(\gamma^\prime(t)-\overline\gamma^\prime(t)\right)
\end{cases}$$
while
$$\begin{aligned}
(\phi \circ \gamma)^\prime(t)=\left(\gamma_x^\prime(t)\frac{\partial \phi_x}{\partial x}+\gamma_y^\prime(t)\frac{\partial \phi_x}{\partial y}\right) + i\left(\gamma_x^\prime(t)\frac{\partial \phi_y}{\partial x}+\gamma_y^\prime(t)\frac{\partial \phi_y}{\partial y}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

and now, you have to replace with the values above...

Comment: Could you show me? I am still a little bit confused. In $(\phi \circ \gamma)'(t)$ I have the real variable t. How could this equal something where I derive to z. I don't even know what z is (in this case).

Comment: I imagine that in your case $A \subseteq \mathbb C$. Right?

Comment: yes (in my book it just says real differnetiable in A, so I will assume it means as subset of C)

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular case of the chain rule for [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Chain_rule), which state that$$\frac\partial{\partial z}(f\circ g)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\circ g\right)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}\circ g\right)\frac{\partial\overline g}{\partial z}$$and that$$\frac\partial{\partial\overline z}(f\circ g)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\circ g\right)\frac{\partial g}{\partial\overline z}+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\overline z}\circ g\right)\frac{\partial\overline g}{\partial\overline z}.$$Note that, in order that this makes sence, you only have to assume real-differentiability.